# Display the first 5 largest values of a DataFrame for each month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm trying to work on a dataframe with a lot of columns (505) and I want to select only the top 5 values for each month. 
You'll find below the link of an image of my DataFrame.

[link photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sbKP.png)

Here is the sample:

```
  Dates         1        2       3           4       5     6
2002-07-31  -31.710916  NaN  -5.208684  -29.773404  NaN -7.308558   
2002-08-31  -44.941351  NaN   3.665286  -23.987135  NaN 3.134669    
2002-09-30  -36.725548  NaN   4.114474  -19.536571  NaN -0.986986   
2002-10-31  -25.377286  NaN  -0.486158  -5.887594   NaN -0.787117   
2002-11-30  19.766328   NaN  -5.298877  -10.672174  NaN -21.057946  
2002-12-31  1.996514    NaN  -7.570497  -9.257122   NaN -19.630112  
2003-01-31  -0.366083   NaN -14.124492  -5.434475   NaN -8.053424   
2003-02-28  -17.869297  NaN -20.075997  1.009837    NaN -11.616974
```

How can I do it? I already tried with df.max(axis=1) but I would like to add 4 other values after the maximum. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post a sample of the dataframe that can be copied and not an image

Comment: Sorry for that, you'll find a sample of my dataframe now

Comment: Your question is still not super clear. It seems one month = one row. Correct? And for each row you want to extract the five largest values out of the 505 columns? Is that right?

What is the expected output from the data table you have presented in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the max 5 columns for each row, since that is the way I interpret your question. The following picks the max 2 rows in your example input, since it has only 4 non-nan columns.

```py
import io
import re
import pandas as pd


# First read in the data you supplied. 
data=io.StringIO(re.sub(" +","\t",
"""Dates         1        2       3           4       5     6
2002-07-31  -31.710916  NaN  -5.208684  -29.773404  NaN -7.308558
2002-08-31  -44.941351  NaN   3.665286  -23.987135  NaN 3.134669
2002-09-30  -36.725548  NaN   4.114474  -19.536571  NaN -0.986986
2002-10-31  -25.377286  NaN  -0.486158  -5.887594   NaN -0.787117
2002-11-30  19.766328   NaN  -5.298877  -10.672174  NaN -21.057946
2002-12-31  1.996514    NaN  -7.570497  -9.257122   NaN -19.630112
2003-01-31  -0.366083   NaN -14.124492  -5.434475   NaN -8.053424
2003-02-28  -17.869297  NaN -20.075997  1.009837    NaN -11.616974"""))
df = pd.read_csv(data,sep="\t")

# Then we preprocess the data, so it is in a long format instead of a wide
df = df.melt(id_vars='Dates',var_name='Column_name',value_name='Value')

# Finally extract the top 2 values for each date, but first set the index so the output knows what column the input came from
print(df.set_index('Column_name').groupby('Dates')['Value'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(2)))
```

and the output is

```
Dates       Column_name
2002-07-31  3              -5.208684
            6              -7.308558
2002-08-31  3               3.665286
            6               3.134669
2002-09-30  3               4.114474
            6              -0.986986
2002-10-31  3              -0.486158
            6              -0.787117
2002-11-30  1              19.766328
            3              -5.298877
2002-12-31  1               1.996514
            3              -7.570497
2003-01-31  1              -0.366083
            4              -5.434475
2003-02-28  4               1.009837
            6             -11.616974
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

It is tough to give a more suitable answer unless you become more explicit with exactly what output you desire.

Comment: Just a last question, I didn't know the melt function and in my case "Dates" is an index so if I use id_vars='Dates' I get a KeyError : "Dates". Is it possible to add an Index with your method? Thanks again

Comment: use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)  to make `Dates` into a column of `df`. [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) also has a lot of options you can play with. In general, the exapmles in the documentation are quite good so look at them!

Answer (score 1):

By reading DocString of method Maybe your looking for `nlargest` method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem is that the nlargest method finds the values per columns and I'm trying the find those values per month which is per rows (and not columns)

Comment: So basically what I want is 5 values per rows

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Dates', freq='1M'))
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ascending=False))
df3 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df3.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Dates', freq='1M')).head(5))
```

**Output:**

```
        Dates          1   2          3          4   5          6
0  2002-07-31 -31.710916 NaN  -5.208684 -29.773404 NaN  -7.308558
1  2002-08-31 -44.941351 NaN   3.665286 -23.987135 NaN   3.134669
2  2002-09-30 -36.725548 NaN   4.114474 -19.536571 NaN  -0.986986
3  2002-10-31 -25.377286 NaN  -0.486158  -5.887594 NaN  -0.787117
4  2002-11-30  19.766328 NaN  -5.298877 -10.672174 NaN -21.057946
5  2002-12-31   1.996514 NaN  -7.570497  -9.257122 NaN -19.630112
6  2003-01-31  -0.366083 NaN -14.124492  -5.434475 NaN  -8.053424
7  2003-02-28 -17.869297 NaN -20.075997   1.009837 NaN -11.616974
8  2003-02-28 -18.869297 NaN -20.075997   1.009837 NaN -11.616974
9  2003-02-28 -19.869297 NaN -20.075997   1.009837 NaN -11.616974
10 2003-02-28 -20.869297 NaN -20.075997   1.009837 NaN -11.616974
11 2003-02-28 -21.869297 NaN -20.075997   1.009837 NaN -11.616974
```